# VS code method documentation tooltip keyboard shortcut

Tags: visual-studio-code

When i write javascript code in VS code and start using a method, the editor shows the method documentation tooltip. Is there a keyboard shortcut to later be able to see that tooltip again?

For example in screenshot i have started writing a *callbackFunction* in array *reduce* method and now would prefer to see the *reduce* method documentation tooltip (marked with red on screenshot) to know where to specify the *initialValue* parameter. Is there a keyboard shortcut, to trigger this tooltip for reduce later when needed?

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6fVa3.png)

Comment: FYI, there's also a [keyboard shortcut to show the hover tooltip](/q/32279384/4518341)

Comment: @wjandrea - the first link provided gave a solution, after method starting parenthese clicking SHIFT + CMD + SPACE triggered the documentation tooltip. Thanks a lot!